# Processing API data as it comes in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, controller, dotnet-httpclient

Is it possible to read API data as it comes, I wrote the below Csharp code in my controller but sometimes the data takes more than 2 minutes and I was wondering if it was possible to load the data in my website as they come instead of waiting for it. Below is my current code:

```
private static async Task<List<Model>> GetFlightData()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
            var content = await client.GetStringAsync(URL);
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(content);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to save the data statically and initialize it on start up,
the problem with this solution is that IIS may restart you website when there's no traffic and the data will be lost (and will cause the next visitor to wait a whole 2 minutes).

The best suggestion I have is to save it to redis/other cache of your chosing and then just pull it from there.